# How to double the size of a dynamic array while keeping the old contents

Tags: c

For part of my C data structures assignment, I am tasked with taking an array of pointers to nodes of 2 doubly linked lists (one representing the main service queue, and the other representing a "bucket" of buzzers ready to be reused or used for the first time in the queue), doubling the size, while keeping the original contents in tact. The idea is that each node has an ID associated which corresponds to the number index of the pointer array map. So for example, the pointer in index 3 will always point to the node whose ID is 3. The boolean inQ is for something unrelated to this issue.

I've written most of the code, but it seems to be functioning incorrectly (it changes all the original pointers to the last node in the list before the array resizing) So, since the starting size of the array is 10 elements, when I print out the contents after the function, it displays 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9.

Here are the structs im using:

```
typedef struct node {
int id;
int inQ;
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
}NODE;

typedef struct list
{
NODE *front;
NODE *back;
int size;
} LIST;

//referred to as SQ in the separate header file
struct service_queue
{
LIST *queue;
LIST *bucket;
NODE **arr;
int arrSize;
int maxID;
};
```

Here is the function in question:

```
SQ  sq_double_array(SQ *q)
{
NODE **arr2 = malloc(q->arrSize * 2 * sizeof(NODE*));
int i;

//fill the first half of the new array with the node pointers of the first array
for (i = 0; i < q->arrSize; i++)
{
    arr2[i] = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (i > 0)
    {
        arr2[i - 1]->next = arr2[i];
        arr2[i]->prev = arr2[i - 1];
    }
    arr2[i]->id = q->arr[i]->id;
    arr2[i]->inQ = q->arr[i]->inQ;
    arr2[i]->next = q->arr[i]->next;
    arr2[i]->prev = q->arr[i]->prev;
}

//fill the second half with node pointers to the new nodes and place them into the bucket
for (i = q->arrSize; i < q->arrSize * 2; i++)
{
    //Point the array elements equal to empty nodes, corresponding to the inidicies
    arr2[i] = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    arr2[i]->id = i;
    arr2[i]->inQ = 0;

    //If the bucket is empty (first pass)
    if (q->bucket->front == NULL)
    {
        q->bucket->front = arr2[i];
        arr2[i]->prev = NULL;
        arr2[i]->next = NULL;
        q->bucket->back = arr2[i];
    }

    //If the bucket has at least 1 buzzer in it
    else
    {
        q->bucket->back = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        q->bucket->back->next = arr2[i];
        q->bucket->back = arr2[i];
        q->bucket->back->next = NULL;
    }
}
q->arrSize *= 2;
q->arr = arr2;
return *q;
}
```

Keep in mind this must only be done in c, which is why im not using 'new'

Comment: I believe you may be looking for `realloc`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `realloc` function:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

Quoted from the man pages:

> The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to
>   by ptr to size bytes.   The
>          contents  will be unchanged in the range from the start of the region up to the minimum of the old
>          and new sizes.  If the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be initial‐
>          ized.   If  ptr  is  NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size; if
>          size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless  ptr
>          is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().  If the
>          area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using it. I was hoping to be able to do it without realloc, but i tapped out due to time constraints.

Comment: @Michael When you get time, you may write your own version of `realloc`. It's just `malloc` + `memcpy` or `memmove`